# How to write a formula to search for the highest 2 numbers and return the numeric values for the header label in excel

Tags: excel-formula

I need to search for the highest 2 numbers by row in ascending order, but return the numeric values with the header label. in the following example, I need to search by row (range A2.D2) and return the first 2 highest number. so the first and second highest nos. are 91 and 71 but I need 91 to be entered as C (header label) and 71 as S. I have multiple files to calculate, so a formula that allows the copy function would work best. At the same time, can the 2 labels be inserted into a single cell?

[image]

Comment: Your question is not too clear to me.  Maybe you can also include what your desired output is?

Comment: I need to compare row B2:D2.  Comparing this row, I need to pick up the highest no. and second highest no.  In this case it is 91 and 71 consecutively.  Instead of inputting 91 and 71, I need to pick up the labels in cells B1:D1.  So 91 will correspond with “C” and 71 with “S”.  Can the output of C and S be input in cell E2?  So E2 would look like “CS”.

Answer (score 0):

How about this in Cell D2?

=INDEX($A$1:$C$1,MATCH(LARGE(A2:C2,1),A2:C2,0)) & LARGE(A2:C2,1) & " " & INDEX($A$1:$C$1,MATCH(LARGE(A2:C2,2),A2:C2,0)) & LARGE(A2:C2,2)

Comment: @Excel Amateur Dan Do you mean the following? =INDEX($A$1:$C$1,MATCH(LARGE(A2:C2,1),A2:C2,0)) & " " & INDEX($A$1:$C$1,MATCH(LARGE(A2:C2,2),A2:C2,0))

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks, it works.  however as I continue to analyse a database in excess of 5,000 rows of entries, I soon realise that there are some unique cases where the first and second highest numbers are the same.  So for example in row three of the table above, the figures corresponding to B, C, D are changed to 10, 92, 92, the output will be "C C" instead of "C D". How should the formula be tweak that it will pick up C3 and D3? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is getting a bit messy, but I've started so I'll blunder on...

I've cheated a bit with this formula by adding a condition that states if the highest and second highest values match, add one to the second hightest value.  You may not be happy with that for whatever reason, but if you are okay with that approach the following horrible forumla is all yours.

```
=IF(LARGE(A2:C2,1)=LARGE(A2:C2,2),INDEX($A$1:$C$1,MATCH(LARGE(A2:C2,1),A2:C2,0)) & " " & INDEX($A$1:$C$1,MATCH(LARGE(A2:C2,2),A2:C2,0)+1),INDEX($A$1:$C$1,MATCH(LARGE(A2:C2,1),A2:C2,0)) & " " & INDEX($A$1:$C$1,MATCH(LARGE(A2:C2,2),A2:C2,0)))
```

Comment: @amateur Dan Feel free to mark this as answered then, :)